# Using asyncio and switching between tkinter windows causes RuntimeError

Tags: python, tkinter, python-asyncio

I just started using asyncio in order to try and make tkinter more responsive when doing blocking tasks such as querying a database.

The issue that I'm having is that when switching between different instances of Tk I get the following error from asyncio: `RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop`

Since pasting the original code would not make too much sense, I trimmed it down to functions that open and close windows and async functions.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Button
import asyncio

async def two():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await one()
    master.destroy()
    window()

async def one():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(one(),two())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    def trigger():
        asyncio.run(main())

    def first():
        global master
        try:
            master2.destroy()
        except Exception:
            pass
        master=tk.Tk()
        Button(master, text="Test",command=trigger).pack()
        master.mainloop()

    def window():
        global master2
        master2=tk.Tk()
        Button(master2,text="Back",command=first).pack()
        master2.mainloop()
    first()
```

Running the code above should throw the aforementioned error.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need more than once instance of `Tk`?

Comment: I know the best practice is to use Toplevel for creating windows on top of root, but I didn't feel like it would be the best solution for my scenario. I have a window that logs the user in, so the login window would be the root and after login I open a dashboard window and close the login. I thought it would not be optimal to have the dashboard window be a toplevel of the login window. This would also mean that I can never quit the login window because the dashboard would be tied to it, thus resorting to hide it.

Comment: Can’t you make the dashboard root and hide it first, make a toplevel login window, and bring back the dashboard upon successful login?

Comment: While I like your idea, it would involve massive changes to the code. The best solution might be having just one single Tk instance, but then all code related to the windows will have to be on the same module.